# Bash: How to redirect output as a specific parameter for a curl invocation?

Tags: bash, curl

Given the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Some processing'
echo 'Some more processing'
echo 'Done.'
```

I wanted to do something like:

```
./script | curl "https://somewebservice.com?token=XXX&input='$0'"
```

At the end of the above script, I want effectively make 3 curls invocations:

```
https://somewebservice.com?token=XXX&input='Some processing'
https://somewebservice.com?token=XXX&input='Some more processing'
https://somewebservice.com?token=XXX&input='Done'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `xargs`:

```
./script | xargs -I {} curl https://somewebservice.com?token=XXX&input='{}'
```

`xargs` will provide every element from the previous pipe to `curl`.

From `man xargs` --> `xargs - build and execute command lines from standard input`.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
a
b
c
$ cat a | xargs -I {} echo www.google.com/{}
www.google.com/a
www.google.com/b
www.google.com/c
```

Comment: But how can I specify that the echo output should interpolated in the URL string at a specific position?

Comment: @IsraelFonseca oh, true. See my update using parameters in `xargs` as described in http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility/